# Can python access control points of Hue modifier?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, video-sequence-editor

I am making a chroma keyer in the VSE and wondered if it possible to access the control point data of the Hue Sat modifier? I would like to build a GUI for easier control of the curve slope but cannot find a reference to these values.

[image]

They seem to have coordinates but no data structure, perhaps this is because you cannot animate their value. But I only want to make interacting with them easier (like the points of a  ramp or blend texture).

Comment: You can try `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.active_strip.modifiers['Hue Correct'].curve_mapping.curves` which returns *3 CurveMaps*. I assume these are the curves for `H` `S` `V`. CurveMaps contain *CurveMapPoints* and those have x y location values as far I can see for now, (I can't test it at the moment) see the datablocks: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PSPnl.png

Comment: Works so far https://gist.github.com/p2or/1f2b725a8c25ce82d69c, but it seems that the curve won't update automatically, might be a viewport issue, not sure.

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Samoth Since the OP wants to generate a custom curve there is a lot more to cover - creating and removing points, set the interpolation type etc. :) I don't have so much time at the moment and I also think the answer would be incomplete until we've found a way to update the curve.Unfortunately calling `scene.update()` does not work on linux nor on windows. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @poor: Well, he didn't ask for a perfect solution, but whether it's possible and you already posted how in this comments and linked some code - you can (for a first step) just pack it together in an answer explaining the open problems as well. And probably you might edit your answer later to show solutions to these problems or explain why it won't be possible in the end. You seem to long for a perfect answer, but this might already help him perfectly without the need to be more perfectionistic. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the ['Control Points'](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CurveMapPoint.html#bpy.types.CurveMapPoint) via [CurveMap](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CurveMap.html) attribute of the respective *Hue Correct Modifier*:

```
>>> h, s, v = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.modifi‌​ers['Hue Correct'].curve_mapping.curves
>>> print (h.points, s.points, v.points)
>>> [p.location for p in s.points]  # print saturation vector control points
>>> s.points[3].location[1] = 0.001 # assignment (y location)
```

To update the representation of the *Curve* within the UI call [`CurveMapping.update()`](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CurveMapping.html#bpy.types.CurveMapping.update) after any assignment. However this does *not update the Viewer*, so toggling the 'visibility' [image] of the modifier is probably the easiest and fastest way to *update the Curve* and refreshing the *Viewer* at once.

#### Desaturate blue(s)

[image]

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
act_strip = scn.sequence_editor.active_strip
hue_modifier = act_strip.modifiers["Hue Correct"]
            
# get the mapping 
# .../bpy.types.CurveMapping.html#bpy.types.CurveMapping
mapping = hue_modifier.curve_mapping

# get the curve maps
# .../bpy.types.CurveMap.html#bpy.types.CurveMap
hue, sat, val = mapping.curves

# iterate through saturation control points
for count, point in enumerate(sat.points):
    x, y = point.location
    
    # desaturate blue
    if 0.55 <= x <= 0.7: # check if x is within the blue range
        point.location.y = 0.01
    
    print (count, point.location)

# direct assignment via index operator
#sat.points[5].location[1] = 0 # desaturate blue

# update the curve
# ../bpy.types.CurveMapping.html#bpy.types.CurveMapping.update
mapping.update()

# force viewer update (optional)
hue_modifier.mute = True
hue_modifier.mute = False
```

#### Custom curves

To apply a custom *Curve* iterate through [CurveMap.points](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CurveMapPoint.html#bpy.types.CurveMapPoint) and assign a [Vector((x, y))](https://www.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils#mathutils.Vector) to each [Point.location](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CurveMapPoint.html#bpy.types.CurveMapPoint.location) (0-1 float range). The following operator allows to reset the number of points as well as the point locations to the default values for demonstration purposes:

[image]
*Click to enlarge*

**Reset Curves Operator (Blender 2.8+)**

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator
from mathutils import Vector


def reset_curve(curvemap):
    
    default_points = [Vector((0.0, 0.5)), Vector((0.125, 0.5)), Vector((0.25, 0.5)), 
                     Vector((0.375, 0.5)), Vector((0.5, 0.5)), Vector((0.625, 0.5)), 
                     Vector((0.75, 0.5)), Vector((0.875, 0.5)), Vector((1.0, 0.5))]
    
    if len(curvemap.points) > len(default_points):  # remove waste
        n = 0
        while len(curvemap.points) > len(default_points):
            curvemap.points.remove(curvemap.points[n])
            n += 1
                    
    if len(curvemap.points) < len(default_points): # generate missing points
        n = 0
        while len(curvemap.points) < len(default_points):
            curvemap.points.new(0.1, 0.5)
            n +=1
    
    # set values to default
    for c, point in enumerate(curvemap.points):
        point.location = default_points[c]


class SEQUENCER_OT_resetHueCorrect(Operator):
    bl_idname="sequencer.reset_hue_correct"
    bl_label="Reset Hue Correct"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    # properties
    def modifier_callback(self, context):
        sel_strip = context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip                    
        hue_modifiers = [(str(c), item.name.title(), '') for 
            c, item in enumerate(sel_strip.modifiers) if 
            item.type == "HUE_CORRECT"]
        return hue_modifiers
    
    mod: EnumProperty(name="Modifier", items=modifier_callback)
    hue: BoolProperty(default=True, name="Hue") 
    sat: BoolProperty(default=True, name="Saturation")
    val: BoolProperty(default=True, name="Value")
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        spc = context.space_data
        act_clip = context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
        return (spc.type == 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR' and act_clip.select)

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # get the active strip
        sel_strip = context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
        
        # tagging the area for redraw to update the curve edits
        context.region.tag_redraw() #context.area.tag_redraw()
        
        #for m in sel_strip.modifiers:
        m = sel_strip.modifiers[int(self.mod)]
                    
        # get the mapping 
        # .../bpy.types.CurveMapping.html#bpy.types.CurveMapping
        mapping = m.curve_mapping
        
        # get the curve maps
        # .../bpy.types.CurveMap.html#bpy.types.CurveMap
        h, s, v = mapping.curves
        
        # reset hue
        if self.hue: reset_curve(h)
        
        # reset saturation
        if self.sat: reset_curve(s)
        
        # reset value
        if self.val: reset_curve(v)

        # update the curve
        m.curve_mapping.update()
        
        # toggle modifier visibility to update the viewer
        # -> way faster than sequencer.refresh_all()
        m.mute = not m.mute # respect the state
        m.mute = not m.mute   
        
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Successfully reset {}".format(m.name))
        return {'FINISHED'}
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        sel_strip = context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
        if bool([m for m in sel_strip.modifiers if m.type == "HUE_CORRECT"]):
            return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
        else:
            self.report({"INFO"}, "strip has no hue correct modifier")
            return {'FINISHED'}
        
    def draw(self, context):         
        row = self.layout
        sel_strip = context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
        if len([m for m in sel_strip.modifiers if m.type == "HUE_CORRECT"]) > 1:
            row.prop(self, "mod")
        row.prop(self, "hue")
        row.prop(self, "sat")
        row.prop(self, "val")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SEQUENCER_OT_resetHueCorrect)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SEQUENCER_OT_resetHueCorrect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Oh wow @poor thanks for taking the time. TBH I had mostly forgot this was here. I'll have to try this code out!

Comment: Hmm can't register or run the script? On 2.76 with adjustment layer and hue modifier. But cannot search for sequencer>Hue reset either. Info bar says it runs without warning however?

Comment: Did you ever get a working addon for this? I have been wanting to be able to easily chroma key from the VSE as well.