# How to script the motion blur shutter curve?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, motion-blur

I am trying to script the motion blur shutter curve (image below) for each frame of a render. I want to control the "openness" of the shutter curve with a list of values between 0 and 1. Ideally I would also like to be able to change this from one frame to the next within a single animation. I believe the variable I need to change is `bpy.context.scene.render.motion_blur_shutter_curve`. How do I convert a list of values to a curve and pass it to this variable?

[image]

Comment: Learned a LOT from both answers. Super helpful y'all, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest read the values and create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) out of point positions per frame, which allows to structure as well as access the values in a reasonable way:

```
dict = {
    frame_number : [
        (LOC_X, LOC_Y), 
        (LOC_X, LOC_Y), 
        (LOC_X, LOC_Y),
        ...
    ]
    frame_number : [
        (LOC_X, LOC_Y), 
        (LOC_X, LOC_Y), 
        (LOC_X, LOC_Y),
        ...
    ]
}
```

One pitfall is that the minimum point count for a [curve is 2](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CurveMapPoint.html#bpy.types.CurveMapPoint), means that you can not remove all the points of any existing curve.

The following demo sets the shutter curve based on custom data. Notice that `set_curve()` is a slightly modified version of the `reset_curve()` function from [this Q&A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64461/31447):

```
import bpy

frame_dict = {
    1: [(0.0, 0.0), (0.07, 0.5), (0.25, 0.9), (0.5, 1.0), (0.75, 0.9), (0.92, 0.5),  (1.0, 0.0)],
    2: [(0.0, 0.0), (0.125, 0.44), (0.375, 0.95), (0.5, 1.0), (0.625, 0.95), (0.875, 0.44), (1.0, 0.0)]
}

# Based on 'reset_curve()' from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64461/
def set_curve(curvemap, custom_points):

    curve = curvemap.curves[0] # Get the curve
    # Remove redundant points
    if len(curve.points) > len(custom_points): 
        n = 0
        while len(curve.points) > len(custom_points):
            curve.points.remove(curve.points[n])
            n += 1
    # Generate missing points
    if len(curve.points) < len(custom_points):
        n = 0
        while len(curve.points) < len(custom_points):
            curve.points.new(0.1, 0.5)
            n +=1
    # Set the values and update UI
    for c, point in enumerate(curve.points):
        point.location = custom_points[c]
    curvemap.update() # Optional call


C = bpy.context
shutter_curve = C.scene.render.motion_blur_shutter_curve

# test call
set_curve(shutter_curve, frame_dict.get(2))
```

---

In order to set the curve and render each frame, go through the key-value pair of the `dict` and call [`Scene.frame_set(your_frame)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=scene%20frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set) per iteration to update the scene:

```
for frame, points in frame_dict.items():
    # Set the curve
    set_curve(shutter_curve, points)
    # Set the frame
    C.scene.frame_set(frame)
    # Render the frame
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

*Alternatively* you can setup a [`frame_change_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=frame_change_post#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post) handler which allows to *preview* and *set* your values on the fly, when changing the frame in the timeline (before rendering):

[image]

```
def set_curve_frame(scene):
    shutter_curve = scene.render.motion_blur_shutter_curve
    if scene.frame_current in frame_dict:
        set_curve(shutter_curve, frame_dict.get(scene.frame_current))

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(set_curve_frame)
```

---

Related:

- [Can python access control points of Hue modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46784/can-python-access-control-points-of-hue-modifier)
- [Python Render Specific Frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/python-render-specific-frames)

Answer (score 2):

I think this works (after running, a new text block should appear with a script restoring the curves):

```
import bpy, json

save_name = "load_blur_curve.py"

D = bpy.data
curves = {}
for name, scene in D.scenes.items():
    curve = scene.render.motion_blur_shutter_curve.curves[0]
    curves[name] = [(p.location.x, p.location.y, p.handle_type) for p in curve.points]
    
out = "curves = " + json.dumps(curves, indent=4)
out += '''

import bpy
from itertools import zip_longest

for scene_name, source in curves.items():
    curve_wrapper = bpy.data.scenes[scene_name].render.motion_blur_shutter_curve
    target = curve_wrapper.curves[0].points
    for i in range(len(target) - len(source)):
        target.remove(target[-1])
    for oldp, newp in zip_longest(target, source):
        if not oldp:
            oldp = target.new(*newp[:2])  # probably can init with just 0, 0
        oldp.location.x, oldp.location.y, oldp.handle_type = newp   
    curve_wrapper.update()  
'''

text = D.texts.get(save_name)
if not text:
    text = D.texts.new(save_name)
text.from_string(out)  # OVERWRITE!
```

Comment: Funny, I understood the question in a completely different way. We'll see, UV'd.

Comment: @brockmann when you run this script, it basically generates your script, though it seems your script uses old solutions that are battle-tested, while mine is fresh and perhaps buggy.

Comment: OH and I didn't put anything for the animation. Also I noticed there's an option to add drivers, will test later if it actually works.